# C++ How to Make a Copy of an Object Not Point to the Original Object

Tags: c++, object

I am writing a program to implement a linked list. The list contains nodes that are used to represent terms in a polynomial function. I have a class called `Polynomial` where I instantiate the linked list. The class has methods that allow you to modify the polynomial, including an addTerm method.

In my main, I would like to do something like this:

```
Polynomial p, q;
p.addTerm({ 4, 8 });
p.addTerm({ -3, 2 });
q = p;
p.addTerm({ 5, 6 });
p.addTerm({ 3, 2 });
```

this is the full Polynomial class:

```
class Polynomial {
        Node* Head;
    public:
        Polynomial();
        ~Polynomial();
        void addTerm(Term term);
        unsigned int degree() const;
        double coefficientFor(unsigned int exponent) const;
        void clear();

    private:
        void DeleteInvalidNode();
    };
```

and the constuctor:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial()
    {
        Head = 0;
    }
```

For some reason, though, when I add the terms to `p` after copying `p` to `q` it adds those terms to `q`. From what I understand this is because when you copy an object to another object they point to the same thing. Is there any way that I can fix this to where when I modify `p` it doesnt effect `q`

**EDIT:** I have now made an operator copy assignment function to try and copy the linked list.

I have written the following:

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial& rhs)
    {
        Node* Temp = rhs.Head;

        while (rhs.Head != NULL)
        {
            Temp = rhs.Head->next;
            this->addTerm({ rhs.coefficientFor(degree()), rhs.degree() });
            rhs.Head = Temp;
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

It is not working though since rhs is constant and I am trying to modify it. I am very new to linked lists. How would I go about fixing this to where it can work?

Comment: You probably want to do a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

Comment: Maybe you didn't properly implement the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Please show a [mre] if you want a deeper diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to how you define the "=" operator in the `Polynomial` class. In here, you have to make sure that it's creating new copies of the terms rather than pointing to the contents of the other `Polynomial` object.

Make the following function a `public` function in `Polynomial`:

```
Polynomial& operator=(const Polynomial& rhs){
      /*Not sure the specifics of your functions or the intention of Nodes, so
      if you need to iterate throuch each term in a Polynomial, be sure to do so, 
      and put the statement below within your loop.*/

    this->addTerm({rhs->coefficientFor(rhs->degree()),rhs->degree()}); 

       /*or something to that effect, what matters is being able to retrieve the
       each Term in the rhs (right-hand-side) and adding them to this 
       Polynomial.*/
    return this*;
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I edited my question and added the class and the contructor

Comment: @ParkerHarrelson123 I put the code in my answer! Take it as a strong guideline, and edit it to fit your specific needs!

Comment: When I put this code snippet in, it gives me an error saying 'operator' must be a member function. And then 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all you need to do is add ```Polynomial::``` before ```opeartor=``` in the function header. Hope this helps!

Comment: that was my bad, I forgot to put that in my header file. I seem to be having a hard time iterating through the linked list in the function (I am very new to linked lists). I am adding my attempt at iterating through it to my original post. It doesn't seem to work. Is there any help you could give me with it?

Comment: You don't want to modify ```rhs```. ```rhs``` stands for right-hand-side of the "=" operator. In your ``main```, ```p``` is the ```rhs```. You want to modify ```this```, which in your situation is ```q```. Inside ```operator=()```, you want to take the values (not addresses) of q and create variables that take those in. Then ```AddTerm()``` those variables with ```this```.